# SQL C# interactions not working

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, datatable, sqldataadapter

I'm trying to ping my SQL server with a query for information, and then pass that information into a DataGridView. Though it won't be shown in my code, I do open my DBConnection first and then close it afterwards. My code is shown below:

```
            using (SqlDataAdapter newDA = new SqlDataAdapter(query, DBConnection))
        {
            DataTable Table = new DataTable();
            newDA.Fill(Table);

            dgvOutput.DataSource = Table;
        }
```

I know that query and DBConnection are both functioning because they work in a similar part of the program, but for some reason, newDA doesn't seem to be getting any data from the database here. When I copy the query's value directly into Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and run it, it gets the data just fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you show the query text?

Comment: "I do open my DBConnection first and then close it afterwards."  SqlTableAdapters handle the closing and opening of the connection...  http://stackoverflow.com/a/956469/1449777

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code that you have posted. The problem is either in the way you are displaying the datagridview, or in your query.  I would suggest that you set a break point after newDA.Fill(Table); and check to see if the table is being populated with data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string connectionString = YOUR_NAME_SPACE.Properties.Settings.Default.CONNECTION_STRING;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            DataTable DT = new DataTable();
            con.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(YOUR_QUERYQUERY, connectionString);
            DA.Fill(DT);
            con.Close();
            return DT;
```

Now After putting this code. in you project with little changes. **I hopw you'll get what to change.**

You will have the DataTable. this contain all the content. you can easily put the content to the datagrid view. It's easy.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after staring at my screen for a few hours more, I realized what I was missing:

```
dgvOutput.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
```

Once I entered this, everything worked just fine.